# Does if without else create race condition in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, race-condition, nonblocking

Does if without else create race condition in nodejs?
For Example:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: What potential race condition are you thinking of in that example?

Comment: req.logIn(user, function(err) { . . . } running before either of the if blocks. Perhaps this isn't the best example.

Comment: Perhaps not :-).  The callbacks of async functions run "out of sequence", but any synchronous code always runs to completion.